# How to zoom out in Openlayer in the particular extent?

Tags: openlayers, zoom

I am creating the interaction for zoom in and zoom out using OpenLayers. I am able to achieve zoom in but I am not able to figure out how can I create zoom out to some extent. Here is my code for zoom in

```
$('#zoomin').click(function () {
    removeInteraction();
    $('#map').css("cursor", "zoom-in");
    map.addInteraction(dragBoxInteraction);
    dragBoxInteraction.on('boxend', function () {
        var extent = dragBoxInteraction.getGeometry().getExtent();
        map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
    })
})
```

For zoom out I have written something like this

```
$('#zoomout').click(function () {
    removeInteraction();
    map.getView().animate({
        zoom: map.getView().getZoom() - 1,
        duration: 250
    })
})
```

Using this way I am able to draw a rectangle box and I am getting the extent and I am able to zoom in that extent.

But Using the same feature how will I zoom out?

Comment: Zoom out to what? You cannot draw rectangle bigger than map view.

Comment: True... But I want to draw the rectangle to the current extent and zoom out from that extent.

Comment: I admit I still don't understand zoom out to what? Maybe a picture or two would help.

Comment: If you think about initial extent, just pick up central coordinate after map initialization (map.getView().getCenter()) and zoom level and store it in some accessible variable. After that, on zoom out, just use 'zoom in' to that previously stored extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this function:

```
 const handleSquareZoomOut = () => {
    const dragZoom = new ol.interaction.DragZoom({
      condition: ol.events.condition.always,
      out:true,
    })
    
    map.addInteraction(dragZoom)
  }
```